# How to get innerText of a tag in VBA excluding text from nested tags?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, excel-2007

I am using VBA for web scraping. Below is the html structure and my VBA code.

When I run it I am getting this text `ETA : 2020-08-26 (Reference only, the date will be updated according to shipments).`

But I want to scrape only the date from it `2020-08-26`

```
 <div style="font-size: 14px;">
     <span class="label" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 13px;">ETA : </span>
     <br>
     2020-08-26 
    <span style="color: red; font-size: 12px;">(Reference only, the date will be updated according to 
     shipments).</span>
</div>
```

**VBA Code>**

```
 Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
    
    ie.navigate "http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/sample-page/"
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Set doc = ie.document
    Set elems = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
    MsgBox elems(33).innerText
```

Comment: Once you have the full string, use `Instr` and `Mid` to locate the position of `:` and `(` to isolate the date and then use `Trim` to remove the leading and trailing spaces from it, then set it to a date variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code finds any date of the form `####-##-##`.

```
Cells.Clear
s = "ETA : 2020-08-26 (Reference only, the date will be updated according to shipments)."
ReDim a(1 To Len(s))
For i = 1 To Len(s)
a(i) = IIf(Mid(s, i, 1) Like "#", "#", Mid(s, i, 1))
Next i
fd = "####-##-##"
Cells(1, 1) = s
aa = Join(a, "")
Cells(2, 1) = aa
Cells(3, 1) = Mid(s, InStr(aa, fd), Len(fd))
Cells(3, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

First it splits the string into an array, and replaces all digits with a `#`. Then it uses `InStr` to find a match to the pattern template `fd`, and uses the return value from the match to return the actual date.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the string, you can just use a combination of `Instr`, `Mid`, and `Trim` to get the date:

```
Sub test()
  Dim sSource As String
  Dim nStart As Integer
  Dim nEnd As Integer
  Dim sResult As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  
  sSource = "ETA : 2020-08-26 (Reference only, the date will be updated according to shipments)"
  nStart = InStr(sSource, ":")
  nEnd = InStr(sSource, "(")
  
  sResult = Trim$(Mid$(sSource, nStart + 1, nEnd - nStart - 1))
  If IsDate(sResult) Then
    dtDate = CDate(sResult)
    MsgBox "Success: " & dtDate
  Else
    MsgBox sResult & " is not a date"
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim html, divs, d, c

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = "<div style='font-size: 14px;'><span class='label' style='font-weight: bolder; font-size: 13px;'>ETA : </span>" & _
 "<br>2020-08-26" & _
"<span style='color: red; font-size: 12px;'>(Reference only, the date will be updated according toshipments).</span>" & _
 "</div>"

Set divs = html.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each d In divs
    For Each c In d.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print TypeName(c), c.nodeName, c.NodeValue
    Next c
Next d
```

output:

```
HTMLSpanElement             SPAN          Null
HTMLBRElement               BR            Null
DispHTMLDOMTextNode         #text         2020-08-26
HTMLSpanElement             SPAN          Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by string manipulation or by the path through the DOM. Here is the solution with the path.

```
Sub SelectFromDropdown()

  Dim url As String
  Dim browser As Object
  Dim nodeDiv As Object
  
  url = "Your URL Here"
  
  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  'Istead of (0) it's (33) in your code
  'However, I do not recommend the use of such high indices,
  'as they can lead to unstable behaviour. Just add a div tag
  'before the index and the macro will not work anymore. This
  'does not apply if you loop through an HTML section that has
  'been selected as a container of exactly these div tags.
  Set nodeDiv = browser.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
  
  'To get only the date you can go through the DOM path
  'You want a text node of the DOM (Document Object Model)
  'So innertext doesn't work. You need the NodeValue
  MsgBox nodeDiv.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line? With your html snippet my code do what you want. Have you tried braX' code? It doesn't matter which way you choose.

Comment: 'MsgBox nodeDiv.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue'

This line gives the error. But thanks for your efforts. 

I have not tried "brax's" code I use "JMP 's" code as I also want to change number format after scraping the date from site.

Comment: I just used that line from your code where I am getting error. May be because of that I am getting the error.